# constructing the vector from an array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, constructor, initialization

I have tried to initialize a `std::vector` from an array, but the vector contains zeros although the array is initialized properly.

**code:**

```
lbfgsfloatval_t * k_array = new lbfgsfloatval_t[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    k_array[i] = (lbfgsfloatval_t)i;

vector<lbfgsfloatval_t> k_vector(k_array, k_array+100);

cout << k_array[0] << " " << k_array[1] << " " << k_array[99] << endl;
cout << k_vector[0] << " "<< k_vector[1] << " "<< k_vector[99] << endl;
```

where `lbfgsfloatval_t` works as `double` or `float`.

**output:**

```
0 1 99
0 0 0
```

EDIT: I have found the problem already. It was not related to the code I've posted in this question.

Comment: `std::iota` is a replacement for your hand-crafted loop, and there's absolutely no need for the separate "array", let alone the dynamic allocation on it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed iota is a better solution for increasing sequence. But I'm still wondering what's wrong with the vector initialization.

Comment: Oh, this code [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e136f61ce377e8a0), and rightly so. I don't see anything that would cause the results you describe.

Comment: I found the problem. I overloaded operator =. I initialized another Matrix k_matrix = k_vector. This initialization seems wrong. And it modified k_vector.

Comment: That statement doesn't use `operator=`, it uses the conversion constructor.

Comment: Yes this is only part of my code. Sorry I thought the problem was in the part copied here. So I only copied part of it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the equivalent code to what you have posted, it just uses `int` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int * arr = new int[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        arr[i] = (int)i;

    std::vector<int> vec(arr, arr+100);

    std::cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << " " << arr[99] << std::endl;
    std::cout << vec[0] << " " << vec[1] << " " << vec[99] << std::endl;
}
```

which outputs:

> 0 1 99
>   0 1 99

so the problem you're experiencing is not caused by the construction of vector from an array. You should use some decent debugger to go through your code step by step to understand what is happening in run time.

Also note that `using namespace std;` within a global scope is a bad practice and usually it is much better to stick with `std::` prefixes instead :)

Comment: As I mentioned, the vector code is ok. The mistake was not in this part of the code. I overloaded operator = (in other parts of the code), and I put the input and output on the wrong place of copy function. As input and output are passed in as reference, the input was modified by output(which is by default all zeors). So the input became all zeros too. But thanks any way.

Comment: @user2684645: I haven't noticed your comment where you wrote that you have solved it already :)